# Webpack: Can I get a source map for after babel, before minification?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs, source-maps

I have a fairly basic webpack setup that runs babel and out comes my minified js with a source map.

Now when I run my source map in chrome I get the js before babel and before minification. However I would often like to have my source map after babel but before minification. Is this possible?

**TL;DR** `I want source map to post-babel pre-minifcation. Possible?`

---

---

---

**For completeness**

I run babel-loader 8 with webpack 4

Here is a screenshot from chrome showing the problem. As you can see the `Dropzone` tag indicates this is jsx (and so before babel)

[image: Chrome screenshot with jsx in the source map]

---

Secondly here is my webpack config (not that it actually matters for my question).

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts', 'react'),
    entry: {
        client: './client'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts', 'app'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')],
                        presets: ["@babel/es2015", "@babel/react", "@babel/stage-0"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    externals: {
        // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
        // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
        react: 'React'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Running webpack with -d gives a second set of source maps in chrome that does the trick.

[image]